# Page footer section blank appear in each page

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to add terms & condition only in the last page, i add it under page footer, i add the formula (PageNumber<>TotalPageCount)to print it in the last page, it works fine,but the problem that it reserves and keep blank zone(Page footer section) in each page after the last.
thanks for help,

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I think I figured it out, at least it works in CR 2008.

1. Open Section Expert and add `WhilePrintingRecords; PageNumber <> TotalPageCount` suppression formula to the page footer.
2. Check the "Suppress Blank Sections"
3. Check "Clamp Page Footer"

This should now show the page footer only on the last page without any blank spaces on the other pages.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: i do what you suggess, but it shows me 1/3, it prints 1/2,2/2and in the 1/1 keep all header, details and add my terms & conditions, my goal is to keep it(Terms & conditions) in  the last page

Comment: See added screenshots in my answer.

Comment: See my revised answer

Comment: hello,

i follow your solution, but in my last page it keeps the page header & page footer.

Comment: In your question you say you only want the footer to appear on the last page, so I don't understand your last comment.